# Как сделать анонимного бота с ссылками в telebot python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем привет! Я создаю бота на python telebot по типу анонимных сообщений, но столкнулся с проблемой, я не знаю как сделать ссылки для пользователей
Пример:
t.me/anonaskbot?start=айдипользователя

когда на неё нажимаешь ты можешь отправить сообщение тому кого эта ссылка

Можно ли как-то повторить такое?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: start в ссылке, отправляет команду /start, ни больше, ни меньше. Отправлять сообщения можно просто используя user_id.

Comment: Спасибо, а как это сделать?

Comment: Забиваете в гугл "телебот туториал" и смотрите, ещё лучше было бы полистать документацию, что б сразу на все вопросы ответить

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно у вас не получается. Записываете куда-нибудь id пользователя, потом передаете его в start=1234567890, Бот же получит сообщение /start 1234567890. И уже средствами телебота вытаскиваете id